# Parse Json data and update in sql table via python

Tags: python, sql-server, json, pandas, pyodbc

I'm parsing JSON in python for the first time so couldn't figure out the correct way to get the data.
I'm accessing JSON data from sql table called **"table1"** in python Parsing the data and updating those records back in "**table1**".
So this is my sql table

```
ID   JSON            Street_Numb   Street_Name   Route   sublocality   Country   ...
12  <json_objects>   NA            NA            NA      NA            NA   ...
40  <json_objects>   NA            NA            NA      NA            NA   ...
30  <json_objects>   NA            NA            NA      NA            NA   ...
```

In above table the actual JSON data could not be accumulated so I'm pasting it separately below
JSON

```
 {"results":[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"16","short_name":"16","types":["street_number"]},{"long_name":"Bhagwan Tatyasaheb Kawade Road","short_name":"BT Kawde Road","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Palmgrove Society","short_name":"Palmgrove Society","types":["neighborhood","political"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"16, BT Kawade Road, Palmgrove Society, Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"location":{"lat":18.5132611,"lng":73.907346},"location_type":"ROOFTOP","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5146100802915,"lng":73.90869498029151},"southwest":{"lat":18.51191211970849,"lng":73.90599701970851}}},"place_id":"ChIJo1QsU7nBwjsRiewRdiNc2i4","types":["street_address"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","short_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Jambhulkar Mala, Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}},"location":{"lat":18.508659,"lng":73.9029138},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJJ0lCDMfBwjsRrPmUq2ZOxd8","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}},"location":{"lat":18.4828904,"lng":73.9016832},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}}},"place_id":"ChIJ8TQ7l8LBwjsROUGpMh25HMw","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Prabhag 36","short_name":"Prabhag 36","types":["administrative_area_level_3","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}},"location":{"lat":18.5204303,"lng":73.8567437},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}}},"place_id":"ChIJARFGZy6_wjsRQ-Oenb9DjYI","types":["locality","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"411040","short_name":"411040","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra 411040, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}},"location":{"lat":18.492095,"lng":73.90017759999999},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-64DzdvBwjsRKzv08MBrn18","types":["postal_code"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.16309},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}},"location":{"lat":18.6832564,"lng":74.0300122},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.1447465},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}}},"place_id":"ChIJQ97RPE_AwjsR5zbDDbo3wHI","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":22.028441,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}},"location":{"lat":19.7514798,"lng":75.7138884},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":22.0279091,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-dacnB7EzzsRtk_gS5IiLxs","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39535869999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.4626999,"lng":68.1097}},"location":{"lat":20.593684,"lng":78.96288},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39498069999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.7535159,"lng":68.16288519999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc","types":["country","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["bus_station","establishment","point_of_interest","transit_station"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"location":{"lat":18.510892,"lng":73.906956},"location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5122409802915,"lng":73.9083049802915},"southwest":{"lat":18.5095430197085,"lng":73.90560701970848}}},"place_id":"ChIJ5YdfqcDBwjsR5VJutWLCsfA","types":["bus_station","establishment","point_of_interest","transit_station"]}],"status":"OK"}
 {"results":[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Canal Road","short_name":"Canal Rd","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Empress Garden View Society","short_name":"Empress Garden View Society","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_3"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Canal Rd, Empress Garden View Society, Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510637,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.5102785,"lng":73.9016839}},"location":{"lat":18.510445,"lng":73.90438309999999},"location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5118067302915,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.50910876970849,"lng":73.9016839}}},"place_id":"ChIJ88lKe8fBwjsRCRKukkS6-nM","types":["route"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","short_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Jambhulkar Mala, Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}},"location":{"lat":18.508659,"lng":73.9029138},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJJ0lCDMfBwjsRrPmUq2ZOxd8","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}},"location":{"lat":18.4828904,"lng":73.9016832},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}}},"place_id":"ChIJ8TQ7l8LBwjsROUGpMh25HMw","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Prabhag 36","short_name":"Prabhag 36","types":["administrative_area_level_3","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}},"location":{"lat":18.5204303,"lng":73.8567437},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}}},"place_id":"ChIJARFGZy6_wjsRQ-Oenb9DjYI","types":["locality","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"411040","short_name":"411040","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra 411040, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}},"location":{"lat":18.492095,"lng":73.90017759999999},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-64DzdvBwjsRKzv08MBrn18","types":["postal_code"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.16309},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}},"location":{"lat":18.6832564,"lng":74.0300122},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.1447465},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}}},"place_id":"ChIJQ97RPE_AwjsR5zbDDbo3wHI","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":22.028441,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}},"location":{"lat":19.7514798,"lng":75.7138884},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":22.0279091,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-dacnB7EzzsRtk_gS5IiLxs","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39535869999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.4626999,"lng":68.1097}},"location":{"lat":20.593684,"lng":78.96288},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39498069999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.7535159,"lng":68.16288519999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc","types":["country","political"]}],"status":"OK"}
 {"results":[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Canal Road","short_name":"Canal Rd","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Empress Garden View Society","short_name":"Empress Garden View Society","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_3"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Canal Rd, Empress Garden View Society, Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510637,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.5102785,"lng":73.9016839}},"location":{"lat":18.510445,"lng":73.90438309999999},"location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5118067302915,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.50910876970849,"lng":73.9016839}}},"place_id":"ChIJ88lKe8fBwjsRCRKukkS6-nM","types":["route"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","short_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Jambhulkar Mala, Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}},"location":{"lat":18.508659,"lng":73.9029138},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJJ0lCDMfBwjsRrPmUq2ZOxd8","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}},"location":{"lat":18.4828904,"lng":73.9016832},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}}},"place_id":"ChIJ8TQ7l8LBwjsROUGpMh25HMw","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Prabhag 36","short_name":"Prabhag 36","types":["administrative_area_level_3","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}},"location":{"lat":18.5204303,"lng":73.8567437},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}}},"place_id":"ChIJARFGZy6_wjsRQ-Oenb9DjYI","types":["locality","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"411040","short_name":"411040","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra 411040, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}},"location":{"lat":18.492095,"lng":73.90017759999999},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-64DzdvBwjsRKzv08MBrn18","types":["postal_code"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.16309},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}},"location":{"lat":18.6832564,"lng":74.0300122},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.1447465},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}}},"place_id":"ChIJQ97RPE_AwjsR5zbDDbo3wHI","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":22.028441,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}},"location":{"lat":19.7514798,"lng":75.7138884},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":22.0279091,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-dacnB7EzzsRtk_gS5IiLxs","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39535869999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.4626999,"lng":68.1097}},"location":{"lat":20.593684,"lng":78.96288},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39498069999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.7535159,"lng":68.16288519999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc","types":["country","political"]}],"status":"OK"}
```

So for those column in table whose values are **NA** I wanted them to fill up by extracting the JSON objects from each records.

So here's a code I tried,

```
import pyodbc
import json
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myServer;DATABASE=temp;UID=ADMIN;PWD=abc@123;autocommit=True')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select TOP 3 ID, JSON from table1 where JSON is NOT NULL AND Country is NULL")

ID=[]
JSON=[]

for row in cursor.fetchall():
     ID.append(row[0]) 
     JSON.append(row[1])
    jsonData = jsonResponse["data"]
    for item in jsonData:
        Street_Numb = item.get("Street_Numb")[1]  #access only first address component
        Street_Name = item.get("Street_Name")[1] #access only first address component
        Route       = item.get("Route")[1] #access only first address component
        sublocality = item.get("sublocality")[1] #access only first address component
        Country = item.get("Country")[1] #access only first address component



    for i in data:
           cursor.execute("UPDATE table1 SET  Street_Numb = ?, Street_Name=?,Route=?,sublocality=?,Country=?)
```

So for each JSON object there are multiple address components so from them I just want to access the first address component only.
But can't actually get a way by which it could be done.

Any suggestion would be very helpful.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So for each JSON object there are multiple address components so from them I just want to access the first address component only.

That's your first challenge. The other challenges are:

- the address component type is specified as a *value* in the "types" attribute, so you can't access them by *name*, and
- some types (e.g., "sublocality") can appear more than once.

Inside your `for row in cursor.fetchall():` loop you can save the "ID" and "JSON" column values as simple variables,

```python
id = row[0]
json_string = row[1]
```

You can extract the address component values into a dictionary of lists, and then concatenate the lists into single strings:

```python
address_fields = {
    'street_number': [],
    'route': [],
    'sublocality': [],
    }
json_all = json.loads(json_string)
json_results = json_all['results']
first_address_components = json_results[0]['address_components']
for item in first_address_components:
    for field_key in address_fields.keys():
        if field_key in item['types']:
            address_fields[field_key].append(item['short_name'])
# convert lists to single strings
address_fields = {key: ', '.join(values) for key, values in address_fields.items()}

pprint(address_fields)
```

with the `pprint` (for demonstration purposes only) producing

```
{'route': 'BT Kawde Road',
 'street_number': '16',
 'sublocality': 'Uday Baug, Ghorpadi'}
```

You could then proceed to update the table with code like this:

```python
sql = """\
UPDATE table1 SET Street_Numb=?, Route=?, sublocality=? WHERE ID=?
"""
params = (
    address_fields['street_number'],
    address_fields['route'],
    address_fields['sublocality'],
    id
    )
crsr.execute(sql, params)
```

Comment: Using your code ,it gave an error "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'"

Comment: I used "dumpData = json.dumps(json_string)  json_all = json.loads(dumpData)
json_results = json_all['results']" the above mentioned error went off, but now it produced with new error "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'list'"

Comment: I see that you got your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45789765/2144390).

Comment: Oh, apologies..yes Gord Thompson but the core logic was from your answer ...Thank you for your time and effort..It saved my day...Thanks a ton!...The answer has been accepted!!!

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you are getting a proper json object from the database. If not you can dump and load the data.

```
dumpData = json.dumps(jsonResponse["data"])
jsonData = json.loads(dumpData)
```

The problem is the loop.

```
address_components = data['results'][0]["address_components"]
Street_Numb = None
for item in address_components:
  if 'street_number'in item['types']:
    Street_Numb = item.get("long_name")
```

[DEMO](https://repl.it/KRb3/1)