# Error while loading json in Python

Tags: python, sql, json, spyder, pyodbc

I'm parsing JSON in python but couldn't figure out the correct way to get the data.
I'm accessing JSON data from sql table called **"table1"** in python Parsing the data and updating those records back in "**table1**".
So this is my sql table

```
R_GEOCODE_ID   JSON            Street_Numb   Street_Name   Route   sublocality   Country   ...
12  <json_objects>   NA            NA            NA      NA            NA   ...
40  <json_objects>   NA            NA            NA      NA            NA   ...
30  <json_objects>   NA            NA            NA      NA            NA   ...
```

In above table the actual JSON data could not be accumulated so I'm pasting it separately below
JSON

```
 [{"address_components":[{"long_name":"16","short_name":"16","types":["street_number"]},{"long_name":"Bhagwan Tatyasaheb Kawade Road","short_name":"BT Kawde Road","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Palmgrove Society","short_name":"Palmgrove Society","types":["neighborhood","political"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"16, BT Kawade Road, Palmgrove Society, Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"location":{"lat":18.5132611,"lng":73.907346},"location_type":"ROOFTOP","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5146100802915,"lng":73.90869498029151},"southwest":{"lat":18.51191211970849,"lng":73.90599701970851}}},"place_id":"ChIJo1QsU7nBwjsRiewRdiNc2i4","types":["street_address"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","short_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Jambhulkar Mala, Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}},"location":{"lat":18.508659,"lng":73.9029138},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJJ0lCDMfBwjsRrPmUq2ZOxd8","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}},"location":{"lat":18.4828904,"lng":73.9016832},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}}},"place_id":"ChIJ8TQ7l8LBwjsROUGpMh25HMw","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Prabhag 36","short_name":"Prabhag 36","types":["administrative_area_level_3","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}},"location":{"lat":18.5204303,"lng":73.8567437},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}}},"place_id":"ChIJARFGZy6_wjsRQ-Oenb9DjYI","types":["locality","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"411040","short_name":"411040","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra 411040, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}},"location":{"lat":18.492095,"lng":73.90017759999999},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-64DzdvBwjsRKzv08MBrn18","types":["postal_code"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.16309},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}},"location":{"lat":18.6832564,"lng":74.0300122},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.1447465},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}}},"place_id":"ChIJQ97RPE_AwjsR5zbDDbo3wHI","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":22.028441,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}},"location":{"lat":19.7514798,"lng":75.7138884},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":22.0279091,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-dacnB7EzzsRtk_gS5IiLxs","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39535869999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.4626999,"lng":68.1097}},"location":{"lat":20.593684,"lng":78.96288},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39498069999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.7535159,"lng":68.16288519999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc","types":["country","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["bus_station","establishment","point_of_interest","transit_station"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"location":{"lat":18.510892,"lng":73.906956},"location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5122409802915,"lng":73.9083049802915},"southwest":{"lat":18.5095430197085,"lng":73.90560701970848}}},"place_id":"ChIJ5YdfqcDBwjsR5VJutWLCsfA","types":["bus_station","establishment","point_of_interest","transit_station"]}],"status":"OK"}
 [{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Canal Road","short_name":"Canal Rd","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Empress Garden View Society","short_name":"Empress Garden View Society","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_3"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Canal Rd, Empress Garden View Society, Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510637,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.5102785,"lng":73.9016839}},"location":{"lat":18.510445,"lng":73.90438309999999},"location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5118067302915,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.50910876970849,"lng":73.9016839}}},"place_id":"ChIJ88lKe8fBwjsRCRKukkS6-nM","types":["route"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","short_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Jambhulkar Mala, Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}},"location":{"lat":18.508659,"lng":73.9029138},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJJ0lCDMfBwjsRrPmUq2ZOxd8","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}},"location":{"lat":18.4828904,"lng":73.9016832},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}}},"place_id":"ChIJ8TQ7l8LBwjsROUGpMh25HMw","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Prabhag 36","short_name":"Prabhag 36","types":["administrative_area_level_3","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}},"location":{"lat":18.5204303,"lng":73.8567437},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}}},"place_id":"ChIJARFGZy6_wjsRQ-Oenb9DjYI","types":["locality","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"411040","short_name":"411040","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra 411040, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}},"location":{"lat":18.492095,"lng":73.90017759999999},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-64DzdvBwjsRKzv08MBrn18","types":["postal_code"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.16309},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}},"location":{"lat":18.6832564,"lng":74.0300122},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.1447465},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}}},"place_id":"ChIJQ97RPE_AwjsR5zbDDbo3wHI","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":22.028441,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}},"location":{"lat":19.7514798,"lng":75.7138884},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":22.0279091,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-dacnB7EzzsRtk_gS5IiLxs","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39535869999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.4626999,"lng":68.1097}},"location":{"lat":20.593684,"lng":78.96288},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39498069999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.7535159,"lng":68.16288519999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc","types":["country","political"]}],"status":"OK"}
 [{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Canal Road","short_name":"Canal Rd","types":["route"]},{"long_name":"Empress Garden View Society","short_name":"Empress Garden View Society","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_3"]},{"long_name":"Uday Baug","short_name":"Uday Baug","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Ghorpadi","short_name":"Ghorpadi","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]},{"long_name":"411001","short_name":"411001","types":["postal_code"]}],"formatted_address":"Canal Rd, Empress Garden View Society, Uday Baug, Ghorpadi, Pune, Maharashtra 411001, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510637,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.5102785,"lng":73.9016839}},"location":{"lat":18.510445,"lng":73.90438309999999},"location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5118067302915,"lng":73.9070137},"southwest":{"lat":18.50910876970849,"lng":73.9016839}}},"place_id":"ChIJ88lKe8fBwjsRCRKukkS6-nM","types":["route"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","short_name":"Jambhulkar Mala","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Jambhulkar Mala, Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}},"location":{"lat":18.508659,"lng":73.9029138},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.510584,"lng":73.9071699},"southwest":{"lat":18.5064841,"lng":73.89949709999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJJ0lCDMfBwjsRrPmUq2ZOxd8","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_2"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Wanowrie","short_name":"Wanowrie","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Wanowrie, Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}},"location":{"lat":18.4828904,"lng":73.9016832},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.512962,"lng":73.9174169},"southwest":{"lat":18.480897,"lng":73.8890401}}},"place_id":"ChIJ8TQ7l8LBwjsROUGpMh25HMw","types":["political","sublocality","sublocality_level_1"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Prabhag 36","short_name":"Prabhag 36","types":["administrative_area_level_3","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}},"location":{"lat":18.5204303,"lng":73.8567437},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.6357545,"lng":73.9864569},"southwest":{"lat":18.4134784,"lng":73.7394779}}},"place_id":"ChIJARFGZy6_wjsRQ-Oenb9DjYI","types":["locality","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"411040","short_name":"411040","types":["postal_code"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["locality","political"]},{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra 411040, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}},"location":{"lat":18.492095,"lng":73.90017759999999},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":18.5105018,"lng":73.9287002},"southwest":{"lat":18.4785059,"lng":73.87890030000001}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-64DzdvBwjsRKzv08MBrn18","types":["postal_code"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Pune","short_name":"Pune","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Pune, Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.16309},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}},"location":{"lat":18.6832564,"lng":74.0300122},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":19.38404,"lng":75.1447465},"southwest":{"lat":17.89324,"lng":73.32352}}},"place_id":"ChIJQ97RPE_AwjsR5zbDDbo3wHI","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Maharashtra","short_name":"MH","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Maharashtra, India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":22.028441,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}},"location":{"lat":19.7514798,"lng":75.7138884},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":22.0279091,"lng":80.890924},"southwest":{"lat":15.6024121,"lng":72.659363}}},"place_id":"ChIJ-dacnB7EzzsRtk_gS5IiLxs","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},{"address_components":[{"long_name":"India","short_name":"IN","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"India","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39535869999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.4626999,"lng":68.1097}},"location":{"lat":20.593684,"lng":78.96288},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":35.5087008,"lng":97.39498069999999},"southwest":{"lat":6.7535159,"lng":68.16288519999999}}},"place_id":"ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc","types":["country","political"]}],"status":"OK"}
```

So for those column in table whose values are **NA** I wanted them to fill up by extracting the JSON objects from each records.

So here's a code I tried,

```
         import pyodbc
            import json
            import numpy as np
            import pandas as pd
            cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=myServer;DATABASE=temp;UID=ADMIN;PWD=abc@123;autocommit=True')
            cursor = cnxn.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select TOP 3 ID, JSON from table1 where JSON is NOT NULL AND Country is NULL")


           ID=[]
        json_string=[]

        for row in cursor.fetchall():
 ID.append(row[0]) 
 json_string.append(row[1])

address_fields = {
'intersection': [],        
'political': [],        
'country': [],        
'administrative_area_level_1': [],        
'administrative_area_level_2': [],        
'administrative_area_level_3': [],        
'administrative_area_level_4': [],        
'administrative_area_level_5': [],        
'colloquial_area': [],
'locality': [],
'ward': [],
'neighborhood': [],
'premise': [],
'subpremise': [],
'natural_feature': [],
'postal_code': [],       
'airport': [],
'park': [],                
'point_of_interest': [],
'street_address': [],                     
'street_number': [],
'route': [],
'sublocality': [],
}
dumpData = json.dumps(json_string)
json_all = json.loads(dumpData)

#print(json_all)
#json_all = json.loads(json_string)

id_index = 0
for json_str in json_all:
     address_fields = {
      'intersection': [],        
      'political': [],        
      'country': [],        
      'administrative_area_level_1': [],        
      'administrative_area_level_2': [],        
      'administrative_area_level_3': [],        
      'administrative_area_level_4': [],        
      'administrative_area_level_5': [],        
      'colloquial_area': [],
      'locality': [],
      'ward': [],
      'neighborhood': [],
      'premise': [],
      'subpremise': [],
      'natural_feature': [],
      'postal_code': [],       
      'airport': [],
      'park': [],                
      'point_of_interest': [],
      'street_address': [],        
      'street_number': [],
      'route': [],
      'sublocality': [],
     }
     json_results = json.loads(json_str)
     if not json_results or not json_results[0].get('address_components'):
          id_index = id_index + 1
          continue 
     first_address_components = json_results[0]['address_components']
     for item in first_address_components:
         for field_key in address_fields.keys():
            if field_key in item['types']:
               address_fields[field_key].append(item['long_name'])

     # convert lists to single strings
     address_fields = {key: ', '.join(values) for key, values in address_fields.items()}
     sql = "UPDATE MST_NHB_R_GEOCODE SET intersection=?, political=?, country=?, administrative_area_level_1=?, administrative_area_level_2=?, administrative_area_level_3=?, administrative_area_level_4=?, administrative_area_level_5=?, colloquial_area=?, locality=?, ward=?, neighborhood=?, premise=?, subpremise=?, postal_code=?, natural_feature=?, airport=?, park=?, point_of_interest=?, street_address=?, Street_Number=?, Route=?, sublocality=? WHERE R_GEOCODE_ID=?"
     params = (
        address_fields['intersection'],     
        address_fields['political'],     
        address_fields['country'],     
        address_fields['administrative_area_level_1'],     
        address_fields['administrative_area_level_2'],     
        address_fields['administrative_area_level_3'],     
        address_fields['administrative_area_level_4'],     
        address_fields['administrative_area_level_5'],     
        address_fields['colloquial_area'],     
        address_fields['locality'],     
        address_fields['ward'],     
        address_fields['neighborhood'],     
        address_fields['premise'],     
        address_fields['subpremise'],  
        address_fields['postal_code'],              
        address_fields['natural_feature'],          
        address_fields['airport'],     
        address_fields['park'],     
        address_fields['point_of_interest'],     
        address_fields['street_address'],     
        address_fields['street_number'],
        address_fields['route'],
        address_fields['sublocality'],
        ID[id_index]
     )
     cursor.execute(sql, params)
     id_index = id_index + 1


cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()
```

But this code is giving me error

```
 File "D:/Deepesh/testForUpdateTableJSON.py", line 34, in <module>
    address_fields[field_key].append(item['long_name'])

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Any suggestions on where the code is getting wrong .

Thanks

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: @DYZ updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found you do this:

```
for row in cursor.fetchall():
   ID.append(row[0]) 
   json_string.append(row[1])

dumpData = json.dumps(json_string)
json_all = json.loads(dumpData)
```

Notice the dumpData is two level json. you see that the json_string is an array of json. so when you get the json_all[0], it is actually also a json.  So It complain that TypeError: string indices must be integers. you should do loads first.

I think you should do the update sql for every row, Then you should include update in your for loop.

fix like this :

```
 id_index = 0
 for json_str in json_all:
     address_fields = {
      'street_number': [],
      'route': [],
      'sublocality': [],
     }
     json_results = json.loads(json_str)
     if isinstance(json_results,dict):
         first_address_components = json_results['results'][0]['address_components']
     else:
         first_address_components = json_results[0]['address_components']
     for item in first_address_components:
         for field_key in address_fields.keys():
            if field_key in item['types']:
               address_fields[field_key].append(item['long_name'])

     # convert lists to single strings
     address_fields = {key: ', '.join(values) for key, values in address_fields.items()}
     sql = "UPDATE MST_NHB_R_GEOCODE SET Street_Numb=?, Route=?, sublocality=? WHERE R_GEOCODE_ID=?"
     params = (
       address_fields['street_number'],
       address_fields['route'],
       address_fields['sublocality'],
       ID[id_index]
     )
     cursor.execute(sql, params)
     id_index = id_index + 1
```

Comment: I think we are pretty much closer...Just in the sql table of mine the Original column name is  "R_GEOCODE_ID" instead of  JUST "ID".... so according to your code  I replaced " ID[id_index]" with  R_GEOCODE_ID[id_index] .. but now it gives error that "R_GEOCODE_ID[id_index]

NameError: name 'R_GEOCODE_ID' is not defined"

Comment: yes, see your code carefully. ' ID=[]
json_string=[]

for row in cursor.fetchall():
 ID.append(row[0]) 
 json_string.append(row[1])
'

Comment: you define an ID, and save the R_GEOCODE_ID in ID. So in your python code, the  R_GEOCODE_ID is listed in ID. so you should use ID to get every  R_GEOCODE_ID.

Comment: Ok..strange but I used the same code of yours "sql = "UPDATE MST_NHB_R_GEOCODE SET Street_Numb=?, Route=?, sublocality=? WHERE ID=?"
     params = (
       address_fields['street_number'],
       address_fields['route'],
       address_fields['sublocality'],
       ID[id_index]
     )" And it gave error      ")

  File "D:/Deepesh/testForUpdateTableJSON.py", line 45, in <module>
    cursor.execute(sql, params)

ProgrammingError: ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'ID'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW)")"

Comment: And if your db's first column is  R_GEOCODE_ID, you should update your sql in your code.

Comment: I just follow your code. please refresh your code. if you change the ID to R_GEOCODE_ID. and you just need change ID to R_GEOCODE_ID

Comment: Refreshed the post...now say error on line "  address_fields[field_key].append(item['long_name'])" error  -> "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'"

Comment: sorry, It is a bug . because when you do the loop, after the first loop the address_fields is changed. should be refresh every loop.

Comment: see my new answer pls. move the define of address_fields into your loop.

Comment: Used your updated code, it executed fine but when I saw if those records has been updated or not then I saw none records have been updated it's still showing NULL values in "route" column...are we missing something "cursor.close() cnxn.commit()
cnxn.close()"         Not sure..

Comment: Yeah...Hurray!!! You cracked it. we got it done..Just can't say simple thanks to you ,it would be more than THANKS. Just can't believe it. it's finally working..jus added "cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
cnxn.close()" at the ending of the code.. +100 for you assistance .Once again tons and load of thanks..Much appreciate your effort. :)

Comment: One more bug i guess has happened, in the line "cursor.execute("select TOP 3 ID, JSON from table1 where JSON is NOT NULL AND Country is NULL")
" we are selecting top 3 rows and processing the JSON data, and it absolutely works fine, but when I did TOP 1000 it gave error on line "first_address_components = json_results[0]['address_components']" Error -> "KeyError: 0"..  ??

Comment: maybe there are json_results which is a null array, you should do a check first

Comment: Alright, How could it be applied in above code? if you could please tell

Comment: Refreshed My post with updated code..... But still giving error "if not json_results or not json_results[0].get('address_components'):

KeyError: 0"  If I use query "select TOP 1000 R_GEOCODE_ID, JSON from MST_NHB_R_GEOCODE where JSON is NOT NULL AND Country is NULL"

Comment: please print the json_results to look

Comment: Print(json_results) = {'results': [{'address_components': [{'long_name': '79', 'short_name': '79', 'types': ['premise']}, {'long_name': 'Ramkrishna Pally', 'short_name': 'Ramkrishna Pally', 'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_2']}, {'long_name': 'Panihati', 'short_name': 'Panihati', 'types': ['political', 'sublocality', 'sublocality_level_1']}, {'long_name': 'Barrackpore', 'short_name': 'Barrackpore', 'types': ['locality', 'political']}, {'long_name': 'North 24 Parganas', 'short_name': 'North 24 Parganas', 'types': ['administrative_area_level_2', 'political']},

Comment: Ohh I see here in this record the JSON object started with " {'results': " ; whereas in others it started with just  [{'address_components': [{'long_name': ......

Comment: this is because you has two json format in your db.

Comment: yes, you got it. you can add an if statement to check first

Comment: Yes I used " if not json_results[0].get('results') or not json_results[0].get('address_components'):
          id_index = id_index + 1
          continue 
     first_address_components = json_results[0]['address_components']"  But still get error if not json_results[0].get('results') or not json_results[0].get('address_components'):

KeyError: 0

Comment: sorry, has a problem maybe.

Comment: You are right Line if json_results.get('results'): Gives error

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: But still how do we do like something like exception handling if that record has error then skip that line and proceed to next line?

Comment: yes. you can add a try except into for loop . like this: for json_str in json_all: try :  ....... except: print error

Comment: I m again facing a similar problem relating to JSON structure, I have posted it here  :: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46727952/python-error-while-updating-a-column-in-sql-server"                                                              .If you could kindly help me with this.